# Unexpected error on templated function argument: "cannot convert from 'ref T' to 'ref byte'"

Tags: c#

I have a test class:

```
class Test
{
    void x(ref byte v) { }
    void x(ref sbyte v) { }
    void x<T>(ref T[] a) where T: byte, sbyte
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < a.Length; ++i)
            x(ref a[i]);
    }
}
```

In the Error List window, I am getting the error

> "**Argument 1:** cannot convert from `ref T` to 'ref byte' on the line `x(ref a[I]);`"

Intellisense is also displaying a different message on the line: "The best overloaded method match for 'Test.x(ref byte)' has some invalid arguments". Any ideas why?

I tried to do this, rather than writing explicit overloads for every array type because my actual code has about 20 different "x" routines for 'scalar' types and I didn't want 20 more functions.

Good call on multiple constraints being 'anded', not 'ored', but I got the same error without the constraint.

I understand why the 'ref' in the third overload is not needed, but this interface may eventually reallocate the array and then will need a ref.

By the way: am I right in thinking that a constraint to "struct" will match with any ValueType, including primitive types?

Here is the code as it stands now, with the same error:

```
class Test
{
    void x(ref byte v) { }
    void x(ref sbyte v) { }
    void x<T>(T[] a)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < a.Length; ++i)
            x(ref a[i]);
    }
}
```

Comment: This code doesn't make any sense. `T` has to be `byte` and `sbyte` at the same time?

Comment: I don't think you can have primitives as generic constraints, and if you could, you certainly couldn't constrain a generic type to be two mutually exclusive types.

Comment: You are very much misunderstanding what generics are for and what generic constraints are for.  Your question title indicates the source of your confusion: **generics are not templates**.  Generics have a syntax similar to templates, and usage cases similar to templates, but they are quite different animals.  If you have only two things that a generic type argument can be then simply write two methods; do not attempt to make them generic.

Comment: I note also that there is no need for your third method to take a ref. Based on these misunderstandings I think you may be coming to C# from C++. Array types are automatically passed by reference in C#; you do not need to make a reference to a *variable*, which is what you are doing. You already have a reference to an *array*.

Answer (score 1):

Exact error message given by roslyn is:

```
(8,34,8,38): Error CS0701: 'byte' is not a valid constraint. A type used as a constraint must be an interface, a non-sealed class or a type parameter.
(8,40,8,45): Error CS0701: 'sbyte' is not a valid constraint. A type used as a constraint must be an interface, a non-sealed class or a type parameter.
(11,18,11,22): Error CS1503: Argument 1: cannot convert from 'ref T' to 'ref byte'
```

`byte` and `sbyte` are not valid constrains for generic parameter. In C# you can only use BaseClass, Interface, reference type, value type and new() constraints.

Read [this MSDN article](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb384067.aspx) that explains how to use generic parameter constrains.

For *really* interested, third compilation message was generated by compiler because it tried to recover from errors by ignoring invalid constrain on parameter `T`. Without any constrains it is not safe to use T as `byte`.

Answer (score 0):

The problem here is that you are calling a non-generic method from a generic one and passing a parameter of T to that call.  In order to do this, you need your internal call to call a `xElement<T>` method (I named it this way since you already are using the name `x` to handle the array overall, and your other methods handle an element of the array only).  But then you are back to square 1 because you now need to have a control-flow statement (like switch) in the inner method body, which is what you are trying to avoid.

The real issue here is that templating and generics are not the same thing.  The first tells the compiler to create a copy of the method for every type actually detects at compile time.  The second tells the run-time to find (or JIT-compile if using reflection) a version of the method based on the encountered type.  Since you only provided (fixed, not generic) versions for byte and sbyte, the compiler knows right off that it can't handle the "generic" cases it may encounter at run-time.

More succinctly, in this use-case, yes, you are going to need a switch statement  since true templating in the sense you are trying to use it is not available.

There is another option too, btw, you can use reflection yourself to find the method:

```
typeof(Test)
// Get all public instance methods
   .GetMethods(BindingFlags.Public|
        BindingFlags.Instance|
        BindingFlags.DeclaredOnly)
// Search by name and by parameter type
   .Where(mi => mi.Name == "xElement" && 
        mi.GetParameters()[0].ParameterType = typeof(T))
// Take the first one found
   .First()
// Call it
   .Invoke(this, new object[] { a[i] });
```

Comment: And I should say that you would put the search for the method (everything up to the end of .First()) outside the loop, then call .Invoke within the loop, but this is not very efficient for large volume.